# Bootstrap modal not showing up, and I don't know why *using django-mako-plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [DMP](https://github.com/doconix/django-mako-plus) as the back end to my webpage, but am having trouble getting a modal to pop up on a button click event. I have been over the bootstrap docs, made sure I load jQuery before bootstrap, and made sure I have a data-target set up with a '#' included (basically all of the stuff here on stack overflow). Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="badge">new!</span>Colonial Heritage Foundation</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rent </a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 left-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">terms</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <%block name="content">
            </%block>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal hide" id="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          header
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="well">Blake Wight</div>
</footer>
```

I took out some of the DMP stuff so that it would be just the html.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: at #loginModal replace .hide class with fade

Comment: I have tried that as well... no luck. :(